# How to approve a comment in Drupal when admin is replying to that comment?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-comments

I want to auto approve a comment when an admin is replying to a particular comment. This feature is available in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to write a module you could do that by implementing [hook_comment_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_insert/7):

```
function MODULE_comment_insert($comment) {
  global $user;
  //check for the administrators
  if(in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
    $comment->status = 1; // 0 for unpublished.
    comment_save($comment);
  }
}
```